# How to link UITableView Cell to different ViewControllers in Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have created a UITableView and set everything up so that it pulls the correct Data that I want on the table. The only issue I have is that when I click on an item, I want it to open that viewController

I have set the Storyboard ID up correctly so everything should work but please see my code below incase there's something obvious I've missed:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

     */

    UIViewController *newTopViewController;


    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.section1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];

    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.section2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];

    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 2) {

        NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.section3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];

    }





}
```

I can provide more info if needed

Comment: hi in your storyboard just make segue between view controllers and in segue properties add segue identifier ex "Mylogin" then as below answers just call based on clicked row with identifier

Answer (score 0):

You use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier to create view controller objects.
But you are not presenting the created view controller object so add:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:newTopViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If Identifiers are correct and you set segues in your storyboard then you can just call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:indentifier sender:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either Push yournewTopViewController

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newTopViewController animated:YES];
```

Or Modally Present your newTopViewController

```
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:newTopViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

in the end of your        didSelectRowAtIndexPath Method.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question I believe you should first import all your .h files First.
Then you can go

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {

   FirstViewController *firstController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
   [self presentViewController:firstController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

And so on and so forth